# While loop numbers sum

Tags: java, while-loop

I need help on how to calculate sum of the numbers that while loop prints. I have to get numbers 1 to 100 using while loop and calculate all those together. Like 1+2+3...+98+99+100. I can get numbers but can't calculate them together. Here's my code:

```
public class Loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i = 1;
        while (i < 101) {
           System.out.print(i);
           i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it only print the last sum? If I try to trick the equation it just hangs.

Comment: Are you asking how to declare another variable and add values of `i` to it?

Answer (score 2):

Use another variable instead of `i` which is the loop variable:

```
int i   = 1;
int sum = 0;
while (i < 101) {
  sum += i;
  i++;
}
```

Now `sum` will contain the desired output. In the previous version, you didn't really loop on all values of `i` from 1 to 101.

Answer (score 2):

First either change your sum variable or index variable

```
public class Loops {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sum = 0;
  int i = 1;
  while (i < 101) {
   sum = sum + i;
   ++i;
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Nice calculate index++ and then just add sum and print it

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  Moved the values around a bit to ensure that you add up to 100 and always show the sum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int i = 1;
    long tot = 1;

    while (i < 100) {   
       i += 1;
       tot += i;
       System.out.print("Number :" + i + "  ,sum="+tot);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sum (i) is also your index. So each time you add to it, you're skipping numbers which you want to add to it.

```
public class Loops {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sum = 0;
  int i = 1;
  while (i < 101) {
   //System.out.print(i);
   sum = sum + i;
   ++i;
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Alternatively, use the Gauss sum: n(n+1)/2

So, the end sum is 100(101)/2 = 5050

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Loops {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while (i < 101) {
       sum = i + 1;
    }
    System.out.print(sum);
  }
}
```